# How to get data from PHP with JSON and AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, json

I don't understand how to get data from PHP file with json and ajax. Help me please.

I tried:

addnews.tpl:

```
    $("#send").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "news.php?addnews",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            title: $("#title").val(),
            text: $("#text").val()
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $(".loading").css({
                "display": "inline"
            });
        },
        success: function() {

        }
    }); 
});

$("#send").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "news.php?addnews",
        data: {},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $('.message').html(data.error);
        },
        error: function(xhr){
            $('.message').html('error fetching data');
        }
    }); 
});
```

news.php:

```
    if(isset($_GET['addnews'])) {
    if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        echo json_encode(array("error" => "error."));
    }
    $news->addNews($_SESSION['id'], $_POST['title'], $_POST['text']);
    $smarty->display("template/addnews.tpl");       
}
```

Another question: how to hide json array (text) on the page?

Comment: What response are you getting?

Comment: Why are you invoking two separate Ajax calls with the same click event? And you will need to decide if you want to use POST or GET — can't have both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Untested
Either choose `post` or `get`. `Post` has been used in the below code.
addnews.tpl:

```
$("#send").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "news.php",
        data: {
        title: $("#title").val(),
        text: $("#text").val(),
        addnews: //your add news value
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $('.message').html(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr){
            $('.message').html('error fetching data');
        }
    }); 
});
```

News.php

```
if(isset($_POST['addnews'])) {
    if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        echo json_encode("error");
    }else{
    $news->addNews($_SESSION['id'], $_POST['title'], $_POST['text']);
    // $smarty->display("template/addnews.tpl");
    echo json_encode("success");
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to POST or GET data, both your Onclick Handlers are called at the same time.
You need to separate those two calls and have one which will POST data and one for GETting data.
Also in `news.php` you need to add logic for when you want to POST and when you want to GET
something like

```
if(isset($_GET['addnews'])) {
    if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        echo json_encode(array("error" => "error."));
    }
    $smarty->display("template/addnews.tpl");       
}


if(isset($_POST['title']))
{
    if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        echo json_encode(array("error" => "error."));
    }
 $news->addNews($_SESSION['id'], $_POST['title'], $_POST['text']);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you echo a json_encode you need to return from the code and not print anything after that,
if you do so it will be an invalid json.
E.g

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    echo json_encode(array("error" => "error."));
    return
}
```